# How to use $setUnion on array of object with different object order for updating document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation, mongodb-update

I have this document:

```
{
  "_id": "65b294740c5693e3deac0cea",
  "name": "Islamic Republic Of Iran",
  "population": 95000000,
  "abb": "IRI",
  "cities": [
    {
      "_id": "65b294740c5693e3deac0cf6",
      "name": "Hamedan",
      "population": 10,
      "abb": "HM"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf7",
      "name": "Tehran",
      "population": 50,
      "abb": "TH"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8",
      "name": "Kerman",
      "population": 12,
      "abb": "KM"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf9",
      "name": "Esfahan",
      "population": 25,
      "abb": "ES"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
      "name": "Mashhad",
      "population": 28,
      "abb": "MS"
    }
  ],
}
```

and I want to update the document and save 5 unique cities on the `cities` field by the following array:

```
[
    {
        _id: "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
        name: "Mashhad",
        abb: "MS",
        population: 28
    },
    {
        _id: "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfb",
        name: "Tabriz",
        abb: "TB",
        population: 27
    }
]
```

If you pay attention, the order of the `abb` and `population` fields in this array is not the same as the first array.
I use this update pipeline to update the `cities` field:

```
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "as": "citiesItem",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$citiesItem._id",
              "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$cities",
          [
            {
              "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
              "name": "Mashhad",
              "abb": "MS",
              "population": 28
            },
            {
              "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfb",
              "name": "Tabriz",
              "abb": "TB",
              "population": 27
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "sortBy": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$slice": [
          "$cities",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I expect this object:

```
{
    "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8",
    "name": "Kerman",
    "population": 12,
    "abb": "KM"
}
```

to be erased and this object:

```
{
    _id: "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfb",
    name: "Tabriz",
    abb: "TB",
    population: 27
}
```

is added to the end of the array of `cities`.

But due to the different order of the fields, instead of the city of "Tabriz", the city of "Mashhad" is stored twice at the end of the `cities` field as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "65b294740c5693e3deac0cea",
  "name": "Islamic Republic Of Iran",
  "population": 95000000,
  "abb": "IRI",
  "cities": [
    {
      "_id": "65b294740c5693e3deac0cf6",
      "name": "Hamedan",
      "population": 10,
      "abb": "HM"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf7",
      "name": "Tehran",
      "population": 50,
      "abb": "TH"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf9",
      "name": "Esfahan",
      "population": 25,
      "abb": "ES"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
      "name": "Mashhad",
      "population": 28,
      "abb": "MS"
    },
    {
      "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
      "name": "Mashhad",
      "abb": "MS",
      "population": 28
    }
  ],
}
```

I even tried switching the order of the fields with the `pipeline` below:

```json
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "as": "citiesItem",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$citiesItem._id",
              "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$project": {
              "cities": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$cities",
                  "as": "orderedItemcities",
                  "in": {
                    "_id": "$$orderedItemcities._id",
                    "name": "$$orderedItemcities.name",
                    "population": "$$orderedItemcities.population",
                    "abb": "$$orderedItemcities.abb"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          [
            {
              "_id": "65b2976346bd44878b4ae02b",
              "name": "Mashhad",
              "abb": "MS",
              "population": 28
            },
            {
              "_id": "65b2976346bd44878b4ae02c",
              "name": "Tabriz",
              "abb": "TB",
              "population": 27
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "sortBy": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$slice": [
          "$cities",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I got this error:

> Invalid $set : :  caused by : :  Unrecognized expression '$project'

How can I create a proper pipeline for this?
Is there a way to uniquely combine two arrays in MongoDB based on one of the keys of an object?
For example, should we perform this combination according to the value of the `_id` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your second query, what did I fix:

1. Remove the `$project` and `cities` as not needed.
2. The position of the `abb` field should come first before the `population`.
3. The "Mashhad" `_id` should be "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa" according to the document.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "as": "citiesItem",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$citiesItem._id",
              "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$cities",
              "as": "orderedItemcities",
              "in": {
                "_id": "$$orderedItemcities._id",
                "name": "$$orderedItemcities.name",
                "abb": "$$orderedItemcities.abb",
                "population": "$$orderedItemcities.population"
              }
            }
          },
          [
            {
              "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
              "name": "Mashhad",
              "abb": "MS",
              "population": 28
            },
            {
              "_id": "65b2976346bd44878b4ae02c",
              "name": "Tabriz",
              "abb": "TB",
              "population": 27
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "sortBy": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$slice": [
          "$cities",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F3WsijP09e9)

If you are looking alternative to check the `_id` from the provided input array that exists in the current document and only add when it is not exist, you can use the below query:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "as": "citiesItem",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$citiesItem._id",
              "65b294750c5693e3deac0cf8"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        $reduce: {
          input: [
            {
              "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfa",
              "name": "Mashhad",
              "abb": "MS",
              "population": 28
            },
            {
              "_id": "65b294750c5693e3deac0cfb",
              "name": "Tabriz",
              "abb": "TB",
              "population": 27
            }
          ],
          initialValue: "$cities",
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  {
                    $cond: {
                      if: {
                        $not: {
                          $in: [
                            "$$this._id",
                            "$cities._id"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      then: [
                        "$$this"
                      ],
                      else: null
                    }
                  },
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "sortBy": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "cities": {
        "$slice": [
          "$cities",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N4knBUVCWlK)

Comment: nice, very well